# mongoDB upstart script not starting on ubuntu precise when configdbs are set in the mongod.conf file

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, upstart

i have multiple servers running ubuntu-1204-precise-v20141212 where i have installed mongoDB by following [this instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

By modifying the config file /etc/mongod.conf i have successfully created a replica set and three config servers in order to build a sharded cluster.

However, when it comes to the mongos instance, the upstart script refuse to start, while running the direct command  "sudo mongos --config /etc/mongod.conf" works without problems.
The only line added in this case to the config file is

configdb = host1:27019,host2:27019,host3:27019

as shown in the mongodb [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/)

all the config servers are reachable, as i could see by running the mongos command directly.

Unfortunately, since the mongos instance is not starting, i don't even have a log file under /var/log/mongodb reporting a possible error, and i have no idea how to find out why the upstart script is failing to start :/

Thank you for any advice :)

Comment: What happens when you try to run the command yourself, not in the script? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Is there anything in /var/log/upstart/mongodb.log? It may be under a slightly different name, like just mongo.

Comment: I get no errors if i run the command my self and the mongos instance works as expected.

In the  /var/log/upstart/mongodb.log i actually found an error (thank you, didn't know about it) telling that for some reason configdb is not an option allowed in the INI config file, while if i run "mongos --config mongod.conf" the configdb is accepted. Why? MongoDB version is 2.6.7 :/

Comment: Update: after some reading i've decided to transform the default config file to a file in yaml format (even if mongodb doc states that it is backward compatible). However i ended up in the same situation: mongos --config /etc/mongod.conf works, sudo service mongod start doesn't. The upstart log still complains about the configDB option for some reason i don't understand